# How to change a contact's autocomplete email order in Gmail?

Tags: gmail, google-contacts, gmail-auto-complete

I have always been under the impression that the order of email addresses for a contact is the order in which their autocomplete suggestions will pop up. So if I have a contact with multiple email address and type their name into the `To:` field, the order of the email address listed in the auto complete pop up will be the order in their contact info, and in particular by hitting tab it will auto fill the first email address of the contact info.

Recently, I've noticed that this is not the case sometimes. In particular I have two contacts that recently changed their main email address and Gmail does not want to update the autocomplete popup with the order I expect. Whether this is because it is no recognizing that the "first" email address in the contact info has changed or because perhaps the auto complete order is based on something else (such as the email address with the most volume associated with it), I do not know.

Does anyone know how to have this behave the way I'd like?

**Update**

An answer mentioned removing the offending email address that's been previously the most emailed address, saving, then readding, and saving the contact again. This seems to work temporarily, but reverts within 6-8 hours.

Answer (score 11):

> [Gmail will first suggest the addresses you send mail to most often.](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6597)

If there is an email address you don't want at the top of the autocomplete popup, remove that email address from the contact. Make sure the changes save, then add the email address back to the contact. This should be sufficient to reset the priority for that email address.

Comment: I don't doubt what you are saying given experience, but do you have any documentation/source on the order favoring an address used more often?

Comment: @mindless.panda I edited my answer to include a documented source.

Comment: Thank you. Removing the "offending" address (i.e. the previously most emailed address), saving the contact, then adding the old email address back to the contact works perfectly, now autocomplete  defaults to the address first listed.

Comment: Unfortunately, this seems to revert within 24 hours and the old email is once again the first suggestion.

Comment: I tried it, it doesn't work if the "offending" address is in the @gmail.com domain. Apparently Google favorizes their own services :(