# How do I change the realname connected with an email on GoogleMail?

Tags: gmail

How do I permanently change the name related to an email that I have recieved and sent email to in the past on GoogleMail (gmail.com)?

The user changed their realname (examples: changed surname, changed title etc) but GoogleMail keeps the first historical realname and do not let me change this or updates to the last used?

If we first emailed when they had their account set as "Mr Smith " and now they have "Dr Smith ". Whenever I type smith@somewhere.com in GoogleMail, it use the first used realname ("Mr Smith") and I have to manually change this with an external editor and copy'n'paste in the full realname+email.

I have tried to Google this but only get answers on how to change my own realname, not the stored realname of someone I email. They have changed their realname for their account, but when I email them this is not reflected in the email created.

An earlier question about this did get an answer that only works for a day and then reverts back: [How to change a contact's autocomplete email order in Gmail?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/21910/how-to-change-a-contacts-autocomplete-email-order-in-gmail)

Is it possible to change the realname related to an email or is this an oversight by Google?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to get help from a friend and got the answer:

Click contacts, add the contact with the old realname, edit the contact and change the realname. Save. So far it seem to work, but I will update this answer if this reverts in 24 hours.

EDIT: Still works after 24 hours.

Comment: Tested and still works after several days.